# SQL CASE switch for parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a parameter that can be 1 of 3 possible values 0, 2 or NULL (these are values for an enum 0 is Pending, 1 is UnderReview and 2 is Closed). If it is NULL it should retrieve all regardless of the Status but If it is 2 it should retrieve all the closed ones however if the value is 0 it should retrieve the ones that are pending or under review. This last one means that I want to retrieve records that have a status of either 0 or 1. I have the following code so far and tried with a CASE switch but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrder
    WHERE (CreationDate >= @StartDate AND CreationDate <= @EndDate)
    AND (@POStatus IS NULL OR [Status] = @POStatus)
    AND (@POStatus IS NULL OR [Status] = CASE @POStatus WHEN 0 THEN 1 END)
    AND (@PurchaseOrderIdSearch IS NULL OR PurchaseOrderId LIKE @PurchaseOrderIdSearch)
    AND EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
    ORDER BY CreationDate DESC, PurchaseOrderId DESC
```

I solved it adding an if statement, I was looking for a simpler way to do it to avoid repetition, this is how it looks like now:

```
IF @POStatus = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrder
        WHERE (CreationDate >= @StartDate AND CreationDate <= @EndDate)
        AND (([Status] = @POStatus)
        OR ([Status] = 1))
        AND (@PurchaseOrderIdSearch IS NULL OR PurchaseOrderId LIKE @PurchaseOrderIdSearch)
        AND EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
        ORDER BY CreationDate DESC, PurchaseOrderId DESC
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrder
        WHERE (CreationDate >= @StartDate AND CreationDate <= @EndDate)
        AND (@POStatus IS NULL OR [Status] = @POStatus)
        AND (@PurchaseOrderIdSearch IS NULL OR PurchaseOrderId LIKE @PurchaseOrderIdSearch)
        AND EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
        ORDER BY CreationDate DESC, PurchaseOrderId DESC
    END
```

Comment: It is never good when you don't provide context - without that any suggestions may lead you down the wrong path. Here you have a statement and "parameters" but it is not clear exactly where this statement exists within the application / database relationship. If your application contains this statement, it is better to dynamically add the needed logic to allow for a much simpler parameterization. Otherwise, Erland discusses this in great detail [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: *where column = 2...* which column? Your query's where clause is more complicated than the requirement that you describe.

Comment: It appears that the logic is `... where ... and ( ( @POSStatus is NULL ) or ( @POSStatus = 0 and UnspecifiedColumn in ( 0, 1 ) ) or ( @POSStatus = 2 and UnspecifiedColumn = 2 ) )`. It would likely benefit from `option( recompile )` as Erland explains.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for something like

```
DECLARE @MyParam INT; --Try to set 0, 1 or 2 

SELECT *
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (0),
  (1),
  (2)
) T(Value)
WHERE (Value = @MyParam) OR (@MyParam IS NULL);
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e69ff85c988ef3d9eedce4f24510c2f) to see how it's working.

---

Update:

It seems like you're looking for

```
DECLARE @MyParam INT; --Try to set 0, 1 or 2 

SELECT *
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (0),
  (1),
  (2)
) T(Value)
WHERE 
(
  CASE WHEN @MyParam = 0 OR @MyParam = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
  AND Value IN(0, 1)
)
OR
(Value = @MyParam AND @MyParam = 2)
OR 
@MyParam IS NULL;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c29efe7fc97f7990c3ca73df7ff508f4)